# DL4J: How to calculate Cosine Similarity between INDArray obtained from getWordVectorsMean

Tags: java, nlp, cosine-similarity, dl4j

I have calculated VectorMean of two sentences like this:

```
String demoString1 = "Enter first label";
String demoString2 = "Enter first name";
        Collection<String> label1 = Splitter.on(' ').splitToList(demoString1);
        Collection<String> label2 = Splitter.on(' ').splitToList(demoString2);

        System.out.println("label1:==>"+label1);
        System.out.println("getWordVectorMatrix->INDArray------------------"+vectors.getWordVectorsMean(label1));

        System.out.println("label2:==>"+label2);
        System.out.println("getWordVectorMatrix->INDArray------------------"+vectors.getWordVectorsMean(label2));
```

**Output:**

```
label1:==>[Enter, first, label]
getWordVectorMatrix->INDArray------------------[0.02,  -0.14,  0.07,  -0.10,.............100 dimension vector]
label2:==>[Enter, first, name]
getWordVectorMatrix->INDArray------------------[-0.00,  -0.15,  0.07,  -0.13,............100 dimension vector]
```

Now how I can calculate similarity(Cosine Similarity) between both sentences using their mean ?
I searched, but I couldn't find any API available in DL4J.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method:

```
public static double cosineSimForSentence(Word2Vec vector, String sentence1, String sentence2){
        Collection<String> label1 = Splitter.on(' ').splitToList(sentence1);
        Collection<String> label2 = Splitter.on(' ').splitToList(sentence2);
        try{
            return Transforms.cosineSim(vector.getWordVectorsMean(label1), vector.getWordVectorsMean(label2));
        }catch(Exception e){
            exceptionMessage = e.getMessage();
        }
        return Transforms.cosineSim(vector.getWordVectorsMean(label1), vector.getWordVectorsMean(label2));

    }
```

Method call:

```
System.out.println("Similarity Score between: "+demoString1+" --vs-- "+ demoString2 +":==>"+ cosineSimForSentence(vectors, demoString1, demoString2));
```